# How do I evaluate a TensorFlow tuple?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros([10])
b = tf.zeros([10])
state = tf.tuple([a, b], name='initial_state')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    s = sess.run('initial_state:0')
```

I get the following error with this example:

```
ValueError: Fetch argument 'initial_state' cannot be interpreted as a Tensor.
("The name 'initial_state' refers to an Operation not in the graph.")`
```

It works when I just pass the tensor, but not when I pass the name.
Why can't I pass the name in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in TensorFlow are not tensors, but a list of tensors, and so cannot be fetched as a whole through an operation in the graph. `tf.tuple` will create a few grouping and dependency control operations (`initial_state/group_deps`, `initial_state/control_dependency` and `initial_state/control_dependency_1` in this case), but that's about it.

Since `state` is a list, it is a valid `fetches` argument to `Session#run`. One can also build a list of operation names from each tuple element and use that instead.

```
s = sess.run(['zeros:0', 'zeros_1:0'])
# [
#  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32),
#  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @E_net4 will behave is nice. But First, you should know how tf.tuple work.
As in the tf.tuple documentation says

```
tf.tuple( tensors, control_inputs=None, name=None )
```

> You have to sometime follow the instruction. But it hard to understand there as no example shown so see mine :

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable([5])

b = tf.Variable([6])

c = a+b
d = a*b
e = a/b

ops = tf.tuple([c,d,e])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ee = sess.run(ops)
    print(ee)
```

Here `ops = tf.tuple([tensor1,tensor2,...],control_inputs=c_ops)`

The output shows :

```
[array([11], dtype=int32), array([30], dtype=int32), array([0.83333333])]`
```